# Middleman Slim template - is there a way to pass variables into YAML front matter?

Tags: ruby, yaml, slim-lang, middleman

I'm using Middleman and Slim templates.

I am proxying data to create multiple pages automatically. I need to set YAML front matter with variables and I don't know how to do that! Does anyone know?

E.g.

In config.rb

```
data.videos.expert_challenge_videos.each do |v|
  proxy "/live/expertchallenge/#{v.slug}.html", "/live/expertchallenge/template.html", :locals => { :v => v }, :ignore => true
end
```

In template.html.slim

```
---
title: Expert Challenge - #{v.name}
---
.live-single-video

  == partial 'header'

  .spacer

  .grid-container
    .grid-100.heading
      == image_tag "label-expertchallenge.png", alt: ''
  .grid-container
    .grid-100.video-container
      iframe src="http://area.autodesk.com/areaadmin/ooyala/show/ZobHQ4NzrsYP4CNnu2EijUGDRztihF7j/1000/562" width="1000" height="562" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen="webkitAllowFullScreen" mozallowfullscreen="mozallowfullscreen" allowFullScreen="allowFullScreen"

  .grid-container
    .grid-50.video-description
      .name
        | <b>Name:</b> #{v.name}
      .date
        | <b>Date:</b> #{v.date}
      .topics
        | <b>Topics:</b> #{v.topics}
    .grid-50.video-share
      | <div class="fb-like" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="200" data-show-faces="false" data-href="#{endpoint}/live/expertchallenge/#{v.slug}.html"></div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      | <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="#{endpoint}/live/expertchallenge/#{v.slug}.html" data-via="Autodesk_ME" data-text="#{v.name}">Tweet</a>

== partial 'footer'
```

Answer (score 4):

In your config.rb add the line:

```
set :frontmatter_extensions, %w(.html .slim)
```

This should do the trick.